# For C++ Random Access Iterator (vector iterator), how is the difference between iterators calculated?

Tags: c++, iterator, random-access

I have following code to randomize the elements in a Random Access Iterator (`vector<int>::iterator`) -

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class RandomAccesIterator>
void randomize(RandomAccesIterator iterBegin, RandomAccesIterator iterEnd)
{
    while (iterBegin != iterEnd)
    {
        int rand1 = rand();
        auto iterdiff = iterEnd - iterBegin;
        auto secondarg = iterBegin + rand1 % (iterdiff);
        iter_swap(iterBegin, secondarg);
        ++iterBegin;
    }
}
```

And following is the main() function:

```
int main()
{
    //container used as to apply algorithm to.
    list<int> List = {34,77,16,2,35,76,18,2,56};

    //randomize example.
    cout << "calling randomize on sorted vector: " << endl;
    List.sort();
    vector<int> temp(List.begin(), List.end());
    cout << "before randomize: " << endl;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    randomize(temp.begin(),temp.end());
    cout << "after randomize: " << endl;
    for (vector<int>::iterator it = temp.begin(); it != temp.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
    cout << endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the randomize template function, how is the difference between iterators calculated (iterEnd - iterBegin)?

I tried a couple of things in the immediate window, and it looks like iterEnd - iterBegin is calculated like so (the vector has 9 elements in it, and the below calculation gives 9). I tried with various number of elements in the `vector<int>`, and the answer was correct each time. The computation is for the first time we encounter iterEnd - iterBegin in the while loop (that is, for 9 elements in the vector):

In the immediate window -

1.

```
iterEnd
{-33686019}
    [ptr]: 0x0080f9dc {-33686019}
    [Raw View]: {...}
```

2.

```
iterBegin
{2}
    [ptr]: 0x0080f9b8 {2}
    [Raw View]: {...}
```

3.

```
0x0080f9dc-0x0080f9b8 //iterEnd - iterBegin gives 36.
36
```

4.

```
36/4 //Dividing 36 by 4, since an integer is 4 bytes (we are iterating over a vector of integers).
9
```

I also tried with 8 elements in the `vector<int>`, and the same type of calculation resulted in 8 elements in step 4. above.

I have a couple of questions here:

1. Are the steps that I am performing to get the number of elements in the vector correct (steps 1. to 4. above)?
2. In step 4. above, I am dividing 36, which is in decimal - by 4 bytes. How is this giving me the correct result? It would make sense if I were dividing 36 bytes by 4 bytes, and then that would give me 9 elements. Why is dividing **decimal 36** by 4 bytes giving me the correct answer?

Please see: I am using the following compiler: Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (Version 16.2.1). The operating system platform is 64 bit, x64-based processor. I am building on Debug x86 environment. The Windows edition is Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This is an implementation detail of the standard library you are using. You should probably not play around with it. If you still want to know what the library is doing, then you should add the compiler/platform you are using to the question, since it will be different for each.

Comment: If that random access iterator is a pointer - which is certainly one option - it's a straight subtraction (subtracting two pointers to `T` gives a `ptrdiff_t` which is a signed integral values, representing the difference/distance between them).    If that iterator is something else, then that "something else" will have been designed in a way that calculating the difference between them makes sense.

Comment: You can look at the MS STL source code to see how `std::vector::iterator` is implemented. It is a [class](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/vector#L236) that just [wraps a pointer](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/vector#L198) to vector's value type.

Comment: Are the iterators for RandomAccessIterator (vector<int>::iterator), contiguous? Only then it would make sense of dividing (iterEnd - iterBegin)/sizeof(int*), and getting the correct result.

Comment: "Are the iterators for RandomAccessIterator contiguous?" Not neccecarily. C++17 adds the category [ContiguousIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator) which vector::iterator models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your steps are correct, but only because:

- `int` happens to be 4 bytes long on *your system*
- `std::vector<int>::iterator` happens to trivally wrap a raw pointer (`int*`) on *your system*

Instead of hard-coding the value 4, you can use `sizeof(int)` to evaluate the correct number of bytes on *any system* you compile your code on.

```cpp
std::size_t numElements = (0x0080f9dc - 0x0080f9b8) / sizeof(int);  // Better
```

As for your second question, the `36` you are calculating is not a unitless decimal value. The raw integer value of a raw pointer (remember: `std::vector<int>::iterator` trivially wraps an `int*` so it has the same size) uses bytes as their implicit unit, so you *are* actually dividing bytes by bytes in your steps.

Finally, I suggest avoiding this sort of pointer arithmetic ([rationale](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-ptr)). The standard already provides a function to calculate exactly this, [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), and it will work correctly across all standard iterators and on any system you compile your code on.

```cpp
std::size_t numElements = std::distance(iterBegin, iterEnd);  // Best
```

Comment: If `iterEnd` and `iterBegin` are of type `int*` then the difference between them are not in bytes but elements, so the division by `sizeof(int)` is unnecessary .

Comment: `std::vector<int>::iterator` is not a raw pointer on OP's system. See [the link](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/vector#L236) to Microsoft's standard library implementation that @Daniel linked in the question comments.

Comment: Seems the implementation simply wraps all of the operations, so I'll just relax my wording.

Comment: It looks like the difference between iterEnd and iterBegin is indeed in bytes. When I changed the vector<int> to vector<char>, I got the following result on doing iterEnd - iterBegin: 0x00bfe151-0x00bfe148 =9. And 9/sizeof(char) gives 9 elements. And there were 9 elements in the vector<char>. As in the OP above, where we had a vector<int> instead, holding 9 elements, following was the result of doing iterEnd - iterBegin: 0x0080f9dc-0x0080f9b8 = 36 bytes. And, 36/sizeof(int) gives 9 (the number of elements in the vector<int>). Am I correct that iterEnd - iterBegin gives the difference in bytes?